# BINARY XML error at #2

Tags: android, xml, binary

I have read lots of question in stackoverflow.But could not find any possible solution for my problem.Please help !
This is my xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Relative Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/background_progress"> 

 <!-- Include Action Bar -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/actionbarlayout" />

 <!-- Include Logo -->

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/logo" ></include>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash_progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/progresstextview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/activity_splash_progress_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="51dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:shadowColor="@color/shadowcolor"
    android:shadowDx="30"
    android:shadowDy="8"
    android:shadowRadius="5"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/mycolor"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

When i am running this in my emulator its perfectly running but its not running in my mobile device and its throwing error.

the error is

```
07-04 18:51:32.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19801): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 18:51:32.437: E/AndroidRuntime(19801): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{com.mcq.android.MCQ/com.mcq.main.ProgressbarActivity}:  java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #2: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must put a width and height on your include tags.

something like this should work:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/actionbarlayout" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/logo" />
```

I don't exactly know why it would work in the emulator, but I don't think it is supposed to.

Comment: Your solution worked.Thanks a lot..Yeah it was working perfectly in emulator.I myself dont knw the reason.Neway,thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Add the layout attributes

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

for example:

```
<include
android:id="@+id/include1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
layout="@layout/actionbarlayout" />


<include
android:id="@+id/include2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
layout="@layout/logo" ></include>
```

Comment: using `match_parent` will make the action bar and logo take up the whole screen I think.

Comment: then make them wrap_content, or if you know what size they occupy assign it directly say android:layout_width="240dp".